# Spark Streaming: How to change the value of external variables in foreachRDD function?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

the code for testing:

```
object MaxValue extends Serializable{
    var max = 0
}
object Test {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        val sc = new SparkContext
        val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(5))
        val seq = Seq("testData")
        val rdd = ssc.sparkContext.parallelize(seq)
        val inputDStream = new ConstantInputDStream(ssc, rdd)
        inputDStream.foreachRDD(rdd => { MaxValue.max = 10 })    //I change MaxValue.max value to 10.
        val map = inputDStream.map(a => MaxValue.max)
        map.print    //Why the result is 0? Why not 10?
        ssc.start
        ssc.awaitTermination
    }
}
```

In this case, how to change the value of `MaxValue.max` in *foreachRDD()*? The result of `map.print` is 0, why not 10. I want to use ***RDD.max()*** in *foreachRDD()*, so I need change `MaxValue.max` value in *foreachRDD()*.

Could you help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general it is better to avoid trying to accumulate values this way, there are different ways like accumulators or `updateStateByKey` that would do this properly.
To give a better perspective of what is happening in your code, let's say you have 1 driver and multiple partitions distributed on multiple executors (most typical scenario)

## Runs on driver

`inputDStream.foreachRDD(rdd => { MaxValue.max = 10 })`
The block of code within `foreachRDD` runs on **driver**, so it updates object MaxValue on the driver

## Runs on executors

`val map = inputDStream.map(a => MaxValue.max)`

Will run lambda on each **executor** individually, therefore will get value from MaxValue on executors (that were never updated before). Also please note that each executor will have their own version of MaxValue object as each of them live in separate JVM process (most often on separate nodes within cluster too).

When you change your code to

`val map = inputDStream.map(a => {MaxValue.max=10; MaxValue.max})`
you actually updating MaxValue on executors and then getting it on executors as well - so it works.
This should work as well:

`val map = inputDStream.map(a => {MaxValue.max=10; a}).map(a => MaxValue.max)`

However if you do something like:

`val map = inputDStream.map(a => {MaxValue.max= new Random().nextInt(10); a}).map(a => MaxValue.max)`

you should get set of records with 4 different integers (each partition will have different MaxValue)

## Unexpected results

### local mode

The good reason to avoid is that you can get even less predictable results depending on the situation. For example if your run your original code that **returns 0 on cluster** it will **return 10 in local mode** as in this case driver and all partitions will live in a single JVM process and will share this object. So you can even create unit tests on such code, feel safe but when deploy to cluster - start getting problems.

### Jobs scheduling order

For this one I'm not 100% sure - trying to find in the source code, but there is a possibility of another problem that might occur. In your code you will have 2 jobs:
One is based on your output from 
`inputDStream.foreachRDD` another is based on `map.print` output. Despite they use same stream initially, Spark will generate two separate DAGs for them and will schedule two separate Jobs that can be treated by spark totally independently, in fact - it doesn't even have to guarantee the order of execution of jobs (it does guarantee order of execution of stages obviously within a job) and if this happens in theory it can run 2nd job before 1st to make results even less predictable

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible. Remember, operations inside of an RDD method are run distributed. So, the change to `MaxValue.max` will only be executed on the worker, not the driver. Maybe if you say what you are trying to do that can help lead to a better solution, using accumulators maybe?

Comment: But when I use code: `val map = inputDStream.map(a => {MaxValue.max=10; MaxValue.max}) ` **(I change MaxValue.max in map())**, the result is 10. Why?

Comment: The result of the map or checking MaxValue.max?